# Can I enable dual channel acceleration for my app?

Tags: android, flutter, networking, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am making an Android flutter app where I connect to a WiFi hotspot which does not have a connection to the internet. While being connected to this WiFi, I need to communicate with an online backend.
After Android 10(from my understanding), some apps i.e. Instragram, Chrome, Facebook and a few more, are able to use a feature called **dual channel acceleration** if enabled in WiFi settings of the device.
I would like to use dual channel network acceleration because it allows the device to use mobile data if this is more stable than the WiFi, without disconnecting to the WiFi.

Is it possible to enable dual channel acceleration in flutter (or maybe just in java/kotlin so I can make a method channel to use it in flutter) ? Or is there another way to work with this issue?